# AndroidStudio Cannot resolve symbol FileUtils

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using android studio 0.8.2 and want to read data from the file to array 
but I get this error: Cannot resolve symbol FileUtils.
Error is in this line:

```
    todoAppNames = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
```

I have included commons-io-2.4.jar file in the app -> libs

```
    public void readItemsFromFile() {                                            
    File fileDir = getFilesDir();//returns absolute path                     
    File todoFile = new File(fileDir, "todo.txt");                           
    try {                                                                    
        todoAppNames = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile)); 
    } catch(IOException e) {                                                 
        todoAppNames = new ArrayList<String>();                              
    }                                                                        
    }
```

If you need any more info please let me know.

Comment: Did you import FileUtils? Try pressing Alt-Ctrl-O and Enter.

Comment: Unrelated: Might I suggest updating Androidf Studio to a newer (stable) version such as 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

Drag the jar file under jar folder of lib, then right click on the jar file and select "Add as library.." option. Dialog box will open up. Select your app and click OK. This will resolve the problem.